# batch populate VAR from external list

Tags: variables, batch-file, set, ip

Been trying to populate my internal VAR from an external CSV from "column 2", I've been trying different combinations and obviously have something fundamentally wrong as I am getting nowhere, I was thinking the for  for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%IP_List%") do was the correct use, but I cannot set this against different variables (see below).

This CSV contains computer names and IP address, I would like to be able to read these in in order and have each 1 set against a different variable.

the list contains

```
computer1 10.1.14.09
computer2 10.1.14.10
computer3 10.1.14.11
computer4 10.1.14.12
```

I would like to set

```
set C1=1st IP address
set C2=2nd IP address
set C3=3rd IP address
set C4=4th IP address
```

So I can calls these later doing something like

```
ping %C1%
```

Or a compare (which I will probably need help with aswell)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon what you show, this will work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "IP_LIST=file.csv"
set "count=0"
for /f "tokens=2 usebackq" %%A in ("%IP_LIST%") do set /a "count+=1" & set "C!count!=%%A"
set C
pause
endlocal
exit /b 0
```

Output:

```
C1=10.1.14.09
C2=10.1.14.10
C3=10.1.14.11
C4=10.1.14.12
...
```